# linq to sql query cannot be translated error

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

Here is the query:

```
children = (from r in masterDB.mrrel_Limited2s
                            join s in masterDB.mrconso_SnoMed2014_LimitedToDiseaseBranches on r.AUI2 equals s.AUI                            
                            join a in masterDB.tbl_patients_problems_problemId_to_SnoMed_Iteration2_before_doc_final_s on s.SCUI equals a.SnoMedScui into aGroup
                            from aa in aGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join g in masterDB.tbl_patients_problems_to_snomed_groups_2014s on s.SCUI equals g.SnoMedScui into gGroup
                            from gg in gGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            where r.AUI1.Equals(node.Value.Split(new string[] { " @ " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0])
                            &&
                            r.REL.Equals("CHD")
                            select new RadTreeNode(
                                s.AUI + " @ " + s.SCUI + " @ " + aa != null && gg == null ? "1" : "0" + " @ "
                                + gg != null ? gg.GroupName : "0" + " @ " + s.SCUI,
                                s.STR
                                )).ToList();
```

I am trying to join two tables where a couple of conditions are met (two where clauses at the bottom) and then left join that set on two more tables. I am getting a "cannot translate query" run time error. All advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error exactly are you getting? There are several possible things that can cause it

Comment: "Could not translate expression \\long expression here\\ into SQL and could not treat it as a local expression"

Comment: One of the main causes of this is where you use functions from csharp that aren't valid in SQL. So your `node.Value.Split` would be an example of this. Do that outside of the linq query separate row and pass the resulting array into the linq.

Comment: Did not fix the issue

Comment: @byc: It fixed one of your issues!

Comment: Edit your question and give the full exception - there is usually useful context in that exception.

Comment: I figured it out. Will add an answer. You put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main causes of this is where you use functions from csharp that aren't valid in SQL. So your node.Value.Split would be an example of this. Do that outside of the linq query separate row and pass the resulting array into the linq.

```
var nodePart = node.Value.Split(new string[] { " @ " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]

children = (from r in masterDB.mrrel_Limited2s
                            join s in masterDB.mrconso_SnoMed2014_LimitedToDiseaseBranches on r.AUI2 equals s.AUI                            
                            join a in masterDB.tbl_patients_problems_problemId_to_SnoMed_Iteration2_before_doc_final_s on s.SCUI equals a.SnoMedScui into aGroup
                            from aa in aGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join g in masterDB.tbl_patients_problems_to_snomed_groups_2014s on s.SCUI equals g.SnoMedScui into gGroup
                            from gg in gGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            where r.AUI1.Equals(nodePart)
                            &&
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with

```
s.AUI + " @ " + s.SCUI + " @ " + aa != null && gg == null ? "1" : "0" + " @ "
                                + gg != null ? gg.GroupName : "0" + " @ " + s.SCUI
```

Changed it to this:

```
s.AUI + " @ " + s.SCUI + " @ " + (aa != null && gg == null ? "1" : "0") + " @ "
                                + (gg != null ? gg.GroupName : "0") + " @ " + s.SCUI
```

and it is seems to be working now. Thanks John for helping me with the other issue